# How to use .avif extension images in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I downloaded an .avif file. It displays correctly in browser and image viewers.

I tried to use it in a React Native (Typescript) project but it says "Unable to resolve module..." as in the attached image.

[image]

File path is correct as I am using .png extension images just fine.

My questions are:

1. Are .avif extension image files supported in React Native?
2. If they are supported how to use them in a Typescript project?

Answer (score 0):

If your device is running on an Android operating system version earlier than 12, it lacks support for the AVIF image format, thereby restricting the ability to view or interact with AVIF images seamlessly.

Here the Documentation of that https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#avif